# All users share the same data created, how do i fix it?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I made a program where users put their expenses to keep track of them, after they create their own account. But when i test it, all users share the same table.

Ex: Lets say user 1, add to the table "Rent: $2500", but when i close that account and open a new one (User 2), i can see the expenses of the other Users in the page. Please help me, I've been putting a lot of time trying to solve it but i cant.
Thanks in advance

Model:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True,blank=True)
date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

        # def __str__(self):
        #   return self.name       (i don't now if it's correct)
    
    
    
    class Finance(models.Model):
        expenses_category = [
            ("Saving", "Saving"),
            ("Food", "Food"),
            ("Bills", "Bills"),
            ("Rent", "Rent"),
            ("Extra", "Extra"),
        ]
    
        expenses_month = [
            ("January", "January"),
            ("February", "February"),
            ("March", "March"),
            ("April", "April"),
            ("May", "May"),
            ("June", "June"),
            ("July", "July"),
            ("August", "August"),
            ("September", "September"),
            ("October", "October"),
            ("November", "November"),
            ("December", "December"),
        ]
    
        customer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True,blank=True)
        category = models.CharField(choices=expenses_category, max_length=200)
        price = models.IntegerField()
        month = models.CharField(choices=expenses_month, max_length=200)
```

Views:

```
@csrf_exempt
def registerPage(request):
if request.user.is_authenticated:
return redirect('home')
else:

            form = CreateUserForm() 
            if request.method == 'POST':
                form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
                if form.is_valid():
                    # form.instance.user = request.user
                    user = form.save()
                    username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
                
                    group = Group.objects.get(name='customer')
                    user.groups.add(group)
    
                    messages.success(request, 'Account was created for '+ username)
    
                    return redirect('login')
    
            context = {'form':form}
            return render(request, 'app_finance/register.html', context)
    
    def loginPage(request):
        username = None
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            username = request.user.customer
            return redirect('home')
        else:
    
            if request.method == 'POST':
                username = request.POST.get('username')
                password = request.POST.get('password')
    
                user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
    
                if user is not None:
                    login(request, user)
                    return redirect('home')
                else:
                    messages.info(request, 'Username or password incorrect.')
    
            context = {}
            return render(request, 'app_finance/login.html', context)
    
    
    def logoutUser(request):
        logout(request)
        return redirect('login')
    
    
    def userPage(request):
    
    
        return render(request, 'app_finance/user.html')
    
    
    
    
    @login_required(login_url='login')
    def homeView(request):
        # customer = Customer.objects.get(id=pk) (not sure#)
        username = None
        items = Finance.objects.all()
        form = FinanceForm(initial={'customer':User})
        if request.method == 'POST':
            username = request.user.customer
            form = FinanceForm(request.POST) # initial={'customer':user}
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        else:
            form = FinanceForm()
            return render(request, 'app_finance/home.html', {'form': form,'items':items})
```

Forms:

```
    class CustomerForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    model = Customer
    fields = '__all__'
    exclude = \['user'\]

        class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
            class Meta:
                model = User
                fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
    
    
    
        class FinanceForm(ModelForm):
            class Meta:
                model = Finance
                fields = '__all__'
```

Template (home.html)

```
<div>
    <span>Hello, {{request.user}}</span> <br>
    <span><a class="hello-msg" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a></span>
</div>


<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <!-- {{ form }} -->

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<br>
<div class="row">
    
    <div class="col-md">
        <div class="card card-body">
            <h1>Expenses</h1>                   
        </div>  
        <div class="card card-body">
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <th>User</th>
                    <th>Category</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Month</th>
                </tr>
                {% for i in items %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{i.customer}}</td>
                        <td>{{i.category}}</td>
                        <td>{{i.price}}</td>
                        <td>{{i.month}}</td>
                        <td>&nbsp&nbsp</td>         <!--add in css -->
                        <td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" href="">Update</a></td>

                        <td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="">Delete</a></td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </table>                                    
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried changing the views' queries but i failed, also modifying the model.

Comment: is it the same case you are getting in your Django admin dashboard?

Comment: @DivyaPrakash Yes, in my admin dashboard all items are in "Finance", inside my app, when i open one object the 'Customer' field is empty, but it let me choose an user. Anyways even if i choose it, it wont change anything in the page, everything keeps the same way. And something i notice is that in the admin page, the users are add in the "authentication and authorization" section, inside the "Users". But they should be in "Customers" , created by my app alongside "Finance". Thank you so much for helping

Comment: @DivyaPrakash also a while back it allow me to create objects inside the page, now it doesnt let me, it throws this error:  RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at / User has no customer.  Maybe the problem is related to this, but i dont understand how to solve it yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are taking all the objects of `Finance` model and sending them to your template. You need to filter it as per the current user. Try fixing this in your code of `homeView`.

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
    def homeView(request):
        # customer = Customer.objects.get(id=pk) (not sure#)
        username = None
        items = Finance.objects.filter(customer_id=request.user.id) # ----> change this as per current user
        form = FinanceForm(initial={'customer':User})
        if request.method == 'POST':
            username = request.user.customer
            form = FinanceForm(request.POST) # initial={'customer':user}
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        else:
            form = FinanceForm()
            return render(request, 'app_finance/home.html', {'form': form,'items':items})
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you so much. But i have another issue, it doesnt let me create another object (only in the admin page) , it give me this error:  "RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at / User has no customer" .  And i would like that the user doesnt have to choose the 'user', because that way they could create an Object for another person

Comment: Can you please add a different question for this? Otherwise, other users will be confused between both problem statements. Thanks.

Comment: Right. Thank you, i just post it as "User can't create objects in the page"